# splitting string from text file : IndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, android, string, split

I have a text file that looks something like this :

```
Aaaaa      0.55     2
bbb        2.1      0.25
ccccc      71       21
.....      ...      ...
ZzZz       0.725    42.92
Total: 746.54
```

I'm trying to get each column and place it inside a String[] for each column.
`readprod[]` will be the first column, `readcant[]` the second and `readpret[]` the third.

```
    String[] readprod;
String[] readcant;
String[] readpret;
int nrz;
int lineCount;
String[] columns;
nrz = 0;
            File root = android.os.Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory();

            File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/.InterSRL");
            dir.mkdirs();
            final File file = new File(dir, str);

            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String line;

                lineCount = 0;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    lineCount++;
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // You'll need to add proper error handling here
            }

            readprod = new String[lineCount];
            readpret = new String[lineCount];
            readcant = new String[lineCount];

            // Read text from file
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    text.append(line);
                    text.append('\n');
                    columns = line.split("\\s+");
                    readprod[nrz] = columns[0];
                    readcant[nrz] = columns[1];
                    readpret[nrz] = columns[2];
                    nrz++;

                }
```

The problem is that i get `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1` at `readcant[nrz] = columns[1];` .

What's the problem ? Is there a better way to read columns from the text file and place them in different strings or arraylists for each column ?

Also : is there a way to split them when there's more then 3 spaces between them? I just realised that the first column,the one with the names can have a value of,for example, `Fish Sticks 200g`..damn...

EDIT : I did this :

```
columns = line.split("\\s+");
readprod[nrz] = columns[0];
Log.d("Listener", "Columns[0]= "+columns[0]);
readcant[nrz] = columns[1];
Log.d("Listener", "Columns[1]= "+columns[1]);
readpret[nrz] = columns[2];
Log.d("Listener", "Columns[2]= "+columns[2]);
nrz++;
```

And this is what i get :

```
07-13 01:55:43.570: D/Listener(15805): Columns[0]= Bulion
07-13 01:55:43.570: D/Listener(15805): Columns[1]= 1
07-13 01:55:43.570: D/Listener(15805): Columns[2]= 2.25
07-13 01:55:43.570: D/Listener(15805): Columns[0]= 
07-13 01:55:43.570: D/AndroidRuntime(15805): Shutting down VM
07-13 01:55:43.570: W/dalvikvm(15805): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d42930)
07-13 01:55:43.575: E/AndroidRuntime(15805): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 01:55:43.575: E/AndroidRuntime(15805): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
07-13 01:55:43.575: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at com.example.testlayout.Administrare$1.onItemClick(Administrare.java:161)
07-13 01:55:43.575: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
07-13 01:55:43.575: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
07-13 01:55:43.575: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
07-13 01:55:43.575: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
07-13 01:55:43.575: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-13 01:55:43.575: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-13 01:55:43.575: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-13 01:55:43.575: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-13 01:55:43.575: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 01:55:43.575: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-13 01:55:43.575: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-13 01:55:43.575: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-13 01:55:43.575: E/AndroidRuntime(15805):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So the problem is when he's getting to the second row..

Comment: whats in columns[0] when you get index out of bounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to split them when there's more then 3 spaces between them?

Yes use this regex  `"\\s{3,}"` Which means 3 or more spaces

[See more on Regular Expressions here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)

Also your last line

> Total: 746.54

Will cause problems unless you handle it

What do you get in your file after that line read?

You could put an if in to check length of columns is 3

```
if(columns.length == 3)
    // Assign your values
else
    // Log error in reading
```

Comment: Hehe,i was just checking this: http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/ and trying to figure out a way to combine them.Yea,i know it will..i remembered it while writing this question.As i did with the fact that my names can have spaces between them as well.i'll take care of it when i get there i guess,heh.Thanks !

Comment: This suggests that there is something in the Input file that is not correct as the line after "Bulion   1    2.25" is not been split or there is nothing in the line that has been read in, see as `columns[0] = `

Comment: Yea,after doing some other stuff i got back to this and indeed,i found the issue.I was writing to the file like this : `String myFormat = "%-20s\t\t%-5s\t\t%-5s%n";` So between every line there was an empty line.My bad,i didn't check the file i was writing,heh.Thanks !